# Java - Add Parameter to Class

Tags: java, class, parameters

I am trying to add a parameter at the declaration of a class.

Here is the declaration:

```
public static class TCP_Ping implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
    }

}
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
public static class TCP_Ping(int a, String b) implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
    }

}
```

(which doesn't work)

Any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: I suggest you [get started in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

About your issue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: Classes aren't `static`.  Methods, instance variables, and initializer blocks can be `static`.  People abuse that, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to declare fields, and get the values of the parameters in the constructor, and save the parameters to the fields:

```
public static class TCP_Ping implements Runnable {
  // these are the fields:
  private final int a;
  private final String b;

  // this is the constructor, that takes parameters
  public TCP_Ping(final int a, final String b) {
    // here you save the parameters to the fields
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  // and here (or in any other method you create) you can use the fields:
  @Override public void run() {
    System.out.println("a: " + a);
    System.out.println("b: " + b);
  }
}
```

Then you can create an instance of your class like this:

```
TCP_Ping ping = new TCP_Ping(5, "www.google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I would've never figured that out!

Answer (score 1):

Use Scala!  This is supported nicely.

```
class TCP_Ping(a: Int, b: String) extends Runnable {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare concrete parameters on the class heading (there are such things as *type parameters*, but that's not what you need as it appears). You should declare your parameters in the class constructor then:

```
  private int a;
  private String b;

  public TCP_Ping(int a, String b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
```